# How return Tuple<T1,T2>

Tags: c#, tuples

I create method where get anonymous types. I want return Tuple. How implement this?

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> GetFiles()
{
    using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
    {
        var query = from pf in context.T1
                    join pfExt in context.T2 on pf.Id equals pfExt.ProcessedFilesID
                    join st in context.T3 on pfExt.WFStatusID equals st.WFStatusID
                    select new
                    {
                        pf.Id,                              
                        pf.RecordCount,
                        pf.Name,
                        pfExt.PackageID,
                        StatusName = st.Name,
                        pfExt.ProtocolStatus
                    };
    }           
}
```

Comment: Well what do you want *in* the `Tuple`'s?

Comment: @user2469940: You can delete the question on yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Something like the following should work:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> GetFiles()
{
    using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
    {
        var query = from pf in context.T1
                    join pfExt in context.T2 on pf.Id equals pfExt.ProcessedFilesID
                    join st in context.T3 on pfExt.WFStatusID equals st.WFStatusID
                    select new { pf, pfExt, st };
        return query.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.pf, x.pfExt, x.st));
    }           
}
```

Comment: Why `AsEnumerable`? It's already an enumerable. And why the separation in the first place? Why not do the select as part of the original query?

Comment: It's an `IQueryable`, and if you try to do `Tuple.Create` on `IQueryable`, LINQ provider *will* crash. You have to move to LINQ to Objects to create a tuple. I'd generally argue that it would be probably clearer to introduce a separate, lightweight DTO-like class here instead of 3 - 5 element tuple, but that's a whole different discussion :)

Comment: @KentBoogaart: No, it actually is an `IQueryable<T>`. Without the `AsEnumerable`, the `Select` would be `Queryable.Select` and not `Enumerable.Select`. The result would be that the tuple creation would be passed to EF, which might not support it.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea this was EF. Thought it was just objects.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: It isn't mentioned explicitly anywhere, you are right. However, the `context` and `TestEntities` gives it away.

Comment: Signature of `GetFiles` shouldn't have generic type parameters, but instead the actual types being comprised in the tuple. I think that might be part of OP's confusion.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: `GetFiles` doesn't have generic type parameters. The tuple actually returns the three actual types used in the query: `context.T1`, `context.T2` and `context.T3` vs `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`. I think the OP just didn't want to disclose the real type names of his code.